# error: bad operand types for binary operator '+' i am not getting where i am wrong

Tags: java, generics

```
public class parent<X> { 
     X x;
     X y;
     X z;
     parent(X x,X y,X z){
         this.x=x;
         this.y=y;
         this.z=z;
     }
     X sum(){
         X t=(x+y+z);
         return t;
     }
    
}

public class Main 
{
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        System.out.println(li);
        parent<Integer> a=new parent(12,20,12);
        System.out.println(a.sum());
    }  

}
```

i am geting this error
parent.java:11: error: bad operand types for binary operator '+'
X t=(x+y+z);
^
first type:  X
second type: X
where X is a type-variable:
X extends Object declared in class parent
Note: Main.java uses unchecked or unsafe operations.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:unchecked for details.
1 error

Comment: You could change it to an interface and implement it with the type you need

Answer (score 3):

The type `X` can be anything, say a class `Cat`. So there is no guarantee that an operator `+` can be applied to it.